# PHP pagination page list adjustment using CSS

Tags: php, html, css, pagination

I have created following pagination (see image);

[image]

here I want to display "Next>>" and "Last" at the end of 28. I cannot change the code to achieve that order because I am using if else block in my PHP code;

Here is the code part;

```
    echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
echo "Page: $page of $last <br>";
echo "Record count: ". $rec_count. "<br>";
echo "Left count: ". $left_rec. "<br>";
echo "Record limit: ". $rec_limit. "<br>";

if( ($page==1) && ($left_rec>0) ){ //this is first page
    echo '<li> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page+1). '"> Next >> <br></a> </li>';
    echo "<li> <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$last\"> Last </a> </li>";
}
else if( ($page>1) && ($left_rec>0) ){
    echo "<li> <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$first\"> First <br></a> </li>";
    echo '<li> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page-1) . '"> << Previous <br></a> </li>';
    echo '<li> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page+1). '"> Next >> <br></a> </li>';
    echo "<li> <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$last\"> Last </a> </li>";
}
else if( ($page>1) && ($left_rec<$rec_limit) ){
    echo "<li> <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$first\"> First </a> </li>";
    echo '<li> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page-1). '"> << Previous <br></a> </li>';
}

/* Displaying page numbers (optional) */
for( $i=1; $i<=$last; $i++ ){
    if( $i==$page ){
        echo "<li> <a class=\"current\" href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$i\"> $i </a> </li>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<li> <a href=\"{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?page=$i\"> $i </a> </li>";
    }
}

echo "</ul>";
```

How can I achieve that using CSS? I have my CSS used so far:

```
    <style>
        ul.pagination{
            text-align:center;
            color:#829994;
        }
        ul.pagination li{
            display:inline;
            padding: 0px 3px; /* here we cannot specify padding for top and bottom because inline display does not support margins and 
                                paddings top and bottom*/
        }
        ul.pagination a{
            color:#0d7963;
            display:inline-block;
            border:1px solid #cde0dc;
            margin:3px 0;
            padding:5px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        ul.pagination a:hover,
        ul.pagination a.current{
            background:#0d7963;
            color:#fff;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: just use, instead of direct `echo` the lines (Next/Last), a variable that holds the line `$next=` `$last=`  and later print it before the `</ul>` like `print $next.$last`. Above all do `$next=$last='';` to prevent errors if Next/Last is not set by your `if/else` lines.

Comment: Make your previous and next elements like blocks using a class.

Comment: while at it, put the whole `<li> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page=` string in a variable too.

Comment: @Error404, Although what others have suggested using variable and printing it later at appropriate place. I would more like to know your solution in demonstration to know how it can be achieved using CSS. Can you please provide the code for that with CSS?

Comment: For example, create a class named `.block` and then associate it to both elements:     `echo '<li class="block"> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page-1) . '"> << Previous <br></a> </li>';
    echo '<li class="block"> <a href="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '?page='. ($page+1). '"> Next >> <br></a> </li>';` Something like this.

Comment: In that class you will have `display: block;` inside. Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Error404, I did as your code shown and added this to style  .block{
    display:block;
   }  But I cannot see any change. :(

Comment: @AmaliPerera does not change anything?

Comment: @Error404. It does not change anythng. It is exactly as before.